# Embedding PHP shortcode in wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

```
<img src="<?php echo $newurl; ?>" alt="01-slide-Eurasia" width="120" height="90" />


<?php echo do_shortcode( '[simple_tooltip content="Click Now to Download"]' . $f . '[/simple_tooltip]' ); ?>
```

I need `$f` need to replaced with `<img src="<?php echo $newurl; ?>" alt="01-slide-Eurasia" width="120" height="90" />`

I tried but, gets error. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the php variable must not be echoed but concatenated in the string.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[simple_tooltip content="Click Now to Download"]<img src="'.$newurl.'" alt="01-slide-Eurasia" width="120" height="90" />[/simple_tooltip]' ); ?>
```